# Is there difference between adding an http link vs making the link find its path?

Tags: html, apache

I'm making a website now, and the user is able to upload his profile image. So I have a problem: I'm storing the image path in database like 
`../profile/userID/img.jpeg`, and the website contains sub-folders.

So my question is: If I used an absolute path like `http://localhost/website/profile/userID/img.jpg`, is this right while the site is live, or is there any disadvantage in server time or any difference from generating a path like in the first example?

Comment: The ideal way is to not store the image path in the database at all, construct it on the fly from the user's data (like their ID).

Comment: i will make sure to do this , thank you :)